# How to write files on smart cards in C#

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu

I'd like to write to file in a processor smart card that accepts APDU commands.
Do you know any examples in C# or smartcard sdk?

Has anyone used http://code.google.com/p/pcsc-sharp/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to create a managed wrapper for WinScard dll. WinScard is Microsoft's implementation of PC/SC. You will need this dll to send and receive APDUs from the card.

Next, you need to know what is the OS of the smart card you are going to use. You must have the API documentation of the smart card. This will help you construct the correct APDUs for writing a file. In the smart card world, there is no single, generic way to create a file. It all depends on the card's OS.

Comment: I have not actually used pcsc-sharp. In my previous commercial application, I have created the pc/sc wrapper myself. 

pcsc-sharp is under 2-clause BSD license and there are some provisions in the clause that my client doesn't like.

Answer (score 1):

Subsembly is what we use. We don't do much with it, but it should get you started.

http://www.smartcard-api.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article in CodeProject call "[A Smart Card Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/smartcardapi.aspx)" that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

pcsc-sharp mentioned at your link above is not really actively maintained. However, I have had great success with Daniel Müller's library with the same name ([pcsc-sharp](http://danm.de/index.php?action=source))

The docs [here](http://danm.de/docs/pcsc-sharp/index.html) are quite good, and the library itself has worked for me very well on both 32bit and 64bit windows *and* linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed my Managed Wrappers of Winscard in C# for sending APDUs and receiving Response from processor based smart cards.

If you don't have the API for the card's OS but you know that it follows ISO 7816 then you can use that standard to construct the APDU.

Let me know if u require more help on the topic. I have been working 4 years now on Smart Cards.